# Use FFmpeg to split a video into equal-length segments

Tags: bash, video, split, ffmpeg

I need to split many videos of unknown length into 2-minute chunks. I can use the accepted answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks to do this, but this would require copying, pasting, and modifying many lines and manually calculating how many 2-minute parts are in each video (not a big deal for a few videos, but after a while it gets really tedious).

I have used code in the past in which all I have to do is specify the input video, the start time, segment length, and the output name and by running it in a .sh file in the same folder as the input video it generates all the necessary separate videos which are labeled "output_video01," "output_video02," etc. However, somehow it doesn't want to work on my new computer. Other answers which claim to be able to do this don't work for me, either (when run as either a .bat or .sh file). I believe the code I previously used was:

```
ffmpeg -i "input_video.MTS" -ss 164 -f segment -segment_time 120 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0:0 -an output_video%d.MTS
```

Another suggestion that doesn't work for me but apparently works for others (see https://superuser.com/a/820773/313829):

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.MTS -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 8 -f segment output_video%03d.MTS
```

I currently have Windows 10 with the anniversary update build in which I have enabled Bash, but for some reason it doesn't want to work. I can't even see the error it gives me because the window closes so abruptly.

Comment: *somehow it doesn't want to work on my new computer.* --> can't troubleshoot if you don't provide details.

Comment: @Mulvya Used to have Windows 7, 64-bit, now have Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: By details, I mean command output and messages.

Comment: @Mulvya I cannot make the script pause long enough to see the particular error messages. I have tried this to no avail: read -p "Press [Enter] key to start backup..."

Comment: I have also noticed that for some reason the program associated with .sh files is Windows PowerShell, which seems wrong, so I associated it with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (as per http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) and it just popped up with the "This app can't run on your PC" error.

Comment: Your ffmpeg command lines are not really bash-specific, try entering them into any command terminal - except for the % sign that might need special treatment because used for variables on windows... then you might at least get any error message which will definitively help (us to help) you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original code (that didn't work for me) was:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.MTS -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 8 -f segment output_video%03d.MTS
```

The code that did end up working for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.MTS -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 8 -f segment output_video%%03d.MTS
```

The "%" needed to be "%%". Also, it worked in a .bat file (not .sh).

Comment: % is a reserved character in windows, so whenever you need to use it in shell command you need to scape it %%

in unix it is not necessary

Comment: If you find that only the first chunk is playable, try adding "-reset_timestamps 1" after segment